# Deploy a React + node.js server app with SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, deployment, https, openssl, backend

I want to deploy my very beautiful app somewhere, but I don't want anybody seing that 'connection not secured' sign or message when using it.... and the suffering began... The main option I tried is deploying the react frontend to vercel, and node js backend to my ubuntu server.... Yes, vercel provides ssl sertificate automatically.. Does it mean there's no way having a secured connection between a usual vercel deployment and a nodejs backen running on some ubuntu server? I tried generating selfsigned cerfs on ubuntu but the ui always say e.g. POST https://my ubuntu ip:8000/auth net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.... PLEASE HELP, how to solve this, or how should I deploy the app to have the secured connection???? Thank you

Please don't be mad for me not providing any code, what's the point? Have you not seen a node js react code?

Is it necessary to install some apache or nginx on my ubuntu server? if yes, what for?
What's the solution? Where should I deploy my app to to have a secured connection??? Thank you